# Bad JSON in X-Dropbox-Metadata header error when getting file from Dropbox API

Tags: java, dropbox, dropbox-api

My app having a problems getting JPG files (while other images are OK) using the Dropbox API.

My code looks like this:

```
DbxRequestConfig config = new DbxRequestConfig("my-awesome-dropbox-app/1.0", Locale.getDefault().toString(), AppengineHttpRequestor.Instance);
DbxClient client = new DbxClient(config, dropboxToken);
DbxEntry.File md;
try {
   md = client.getFile(completePath, null,  outputStream);
} catch (DbxException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
outputStream.close();
```

The error is:

```
[INFO] com.dropbox.core.DbxException$BadResponse: Bad JSON in X-Dropbox-Metadata header: 1.141: "photo_info": expecting the end of an object ("}")
[INFO]  at com.dropbox.core.DbxClient.startGetSomething(DbxClient.java:475)
[INFO]  at com.dropbox.core.DbxClient.startGetFile(DbxClient.java:452)
[INFO]  at com.dropbox.core.DbxClient.getFile(DbxClient.java:412)
```

The weird thing is PNG files does not have this problem. What could be causing this error?

Comment: This seems to indicate that the Dropbox API is returning invalid JSON, but I can't reproduce it. Can you add a breakpoint on `metadata = DbxEntry.File.Reader.readFully(metadataString);` in DbxClient.java and share the value of `metadataString`? Also, what version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: @Greg I'm using `<version>0-SNAPSHOT</version>`

Comment: What version is actually getting installed though? (It sounds like you're using Maven.) The latest version is 1.8.2. If you're not using that, you should upgrade to it. If you're still having trouble, please check and post the `metadataString` value I mentioned.

Comment: @Greg I fixed that by pulling the changes from the Dropbox Java SDK github repository did some mvn install'ing then made some changes in the DbxClient to DbxClientV1 and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this problem was to `git pull` the latest version of the [Dropbox Java API](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java) then do `git install`